# delete unassigned (zero values) in a slice

Tags: go

How to delete all zero values or unassigned values?

Here a stack trace is put into a slice.. How can all the unassigned (zero values) be deleted?

Is there some fancy function to slice a slice.. Something like substring of a string

```
trace := make([]byte, 1024)
runtime.Stack(trace, true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) to trim the unused portion of the stack buffer. The Stack function conveniently returns the number of bytes written to the buffer.

```
    trace := make([]byte, 1024)
    n := runtime.Stack(trace, true)
    trace = trace[:n]
```

<kbd>[playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/KdF_yt8l68)</kbd>